# SQL Server: how Row Goal affects the same index operation?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, optimization, sql-server-2019

I am tuning some SQL performance in the SQL Server 2019, and I ran into issues with one query that involves the issue with the row goals. The simplified query is:

```
select TOP 1 ISNULL(RUNID,-1)
from T_PROCESS_MONITOR mon WITH (INDEX = IDX_T_PROCESS_MONITOR_RUNID)
WHERE 
        mon.SOURCE = 'Dynamic Export'
        AND
        mon.STATUS = 'PROCESSING'
```

(The index hint is there just to force the optimizer to use the index to match the benchmark)

If I disable row goals by another query hint `OPTION (MAXDOP 1, USE HINT('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'))`, the performance of the query is dramatically different (MAXDOP does not matter in this case). I know the row goal affects the estimated number of rows and based on that I thought it actually adjusts the execution plan. But it is not the case here. The execution plan is exactly the same for both queries, but the one without the row goal is dramatically faster (1s vs 12s):
[image]

Can please anybody explain to me what makes the difference there? Because despite the different estimated number of rows, both index scans read actually the same number of rows from the same index and then I would expect the performance to be the same.

Edit:
The shared execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ7R30o26

Comment: Upload the XML of the actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question. This may provide additional information to help answer your question.

Comment: Can you upload both execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and link them in your Post? There's a lot more details encoded in them not shown in a screenshot.

Comment: I would guess that the faster of the nested loops queries uses optimized nested loop/prefetching, but please post the plans as others have requested.

Comment: I amended the post with the link to the execution plan shared. Thank you all for the comments so far!

Comment: Can you provide a `CREATE TABLE` and synthetic data that reproduces this? For example the following **doesn't** for me despite similar reads and row counts https://dbfiddle.uk/gt6tKhxa

Comment: The only difference I can see is the excessive `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` waits. I'm going to hazard a guess that prefetching is the issue here: it expects huge numbers of rows so aggressively prefetches, not realizing that a) the rows are all in memory anyway b) it doesn't actually need so many rows. Therefore running through the scheduler quantum while pointlessly prefetching, when instead it should have yielded some rows sooner in order to complete the `Top` operator quicker.

Comment: If you can reproduce this at will on a test instance you can use Windows Performance Recorder to see what it is spending CPU time on

Comment: @MartinSmith I tried it couple of times and the difference I spotted there is that for a new table the SQL Server decided not to use row goal estimation at all.